# jQuery UI popup customization and css layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm developing web application based on jQuery. For popup-windows i'm using jQuery UI dialog + jQuery UI tabs + jScrollPpane for custom scroll bars. The main structure is:

1. Header container at the top (height: 60px; ).
2. Container with height: 85%; min-height: 300px; which includes:

   - jQuery UI tabs filled dynamically with data (table inside a container) point (2.1)
   - Save and cancel buttons container with absolute positioning (bottom: 15px; right: 20px;), which should be always at the bottom of popup. point (2.2)

Dialog should be resizable vertically, so the jQuery dialog's resizable option is turned on.

The question is: how to make central container (2.1) fill all space between header (1) and buttons container (2.2)?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have a wrapping container for all your elements. Then with the content container you must set it's position:relative. Then any absolute element you set inside that element can be positioned relative to the parent element.

I worked out the scenario for you as jsbin.com. The fiddler site was not working for me.

So you can paste this in to jsbin to see it work. Note: It will not work the same when running render, the jsbin site and jsfiddler doesn't apply the css properly. These sites were not meant for this reason you can make it work by making the css all inline styles.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .wrapper {border:1px solid black;height:100%;background-color:#DDD }
  .top { border:1px solid black;padding:15px;text-align:center;height:60px;background-color:#BBB;display:block; }
  .tabs {} 
  .tabs li {list-style-type:none; display:inline; border:1px solid #888;padding:3px;background-color:#999}
  .tabs li:hover {background-color:#AAA;}
  .container {position:relative; border:1px solid;min-height:300px;height:85%;}
  .buttonSection {position:absolute;bottom:15px;right:20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="wrapper" >
    <div class="top" style="">
      <p>This is the top maybe a banner?</p></div>

    <div id="container" >
      <div class="buttonSection" style=" " >

        <ul class="tabs" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
        <li>Button 1</li>
        <li>Button 2</li>
      </ul>

      </div>
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
      </ul>
      <p>This is your body Container. I suggest using list instead of using tables for links or tabs.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```